# How can I see if I have software-properties-common installed?

Tags: ppa

I intend to download and install something, but the first pre-requisite says:

> You need software-properties-common installed in order to add PPA repositories.
>   If not installed(...)

and then it shows instructions how to install it.

I haven't used my PC in a long time, so I don't know if I installed it before or not. How can I check that out?

Answer (score 4):

You can query with `apt`, for example

```
apt policy software-properties-common
```

or

```
apt list --installed software-properties*
```

or with `dpkg`

```
dpkg -l software-properties-common
```

However it won't do any harm to follow the installation instructions - you would just get a message like

```
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.24.32.7).
```

if it is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

The `software-properties-common` package [provides](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=add-apt-repository) the `add-apt-repository` command.

So in this case, just try to run the `add-apt-repository` command they want you to run. If it works, everything is fine. Otherwise you will get a "Command not found" error message which should probably even advise you on which package to install to get it:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

However, you could also run this command safely if the package is already installed. It will detect this and not reinstall it again.

Other, general ways to find out whether a specific package is installed are described in [@steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1120719/367990) to this question.